# Out of memory error, but only if i dont console.log the object pushed to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I've been struggling for a while with a script to parse huge csv files. I get an out of memory error, but only if i dont log the object i push to the console...

I cobbled this script together to demonstrate the issue:

```js
function generateRandomString(
  num,
  possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
) {
  let text = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

async function main() {
  const log = true;
  let storage = [];
  let x = 0;

  while (x < 100000) {
    let e = generateRandomString(100);
    let y = generateRandomString(1000);
    storage.push({ e, y });
    if (log) console.log(storage[x]);
    x++;
  }
}
main().catch(console.log);
```

if the `log` variable is set to `false` i get the below error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
on[15564:0x133f620]     6912 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.8 (1425.0) -> 1399.5 (1425.0) MB, 397.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 398 ms) (average mu = 0.094, current mu = 0.002) allocation[15564:0x133f620]     7873 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.2 (1425.0) -> 1399.7 (1425.0) MB, 961.5 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 962 ms) (average mu = 0.029, current mu = 0.000) allocation 

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2c942895452b]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x2c94289556f3]
Security context: 0x0042034aede9 <JSObject>
    2: main [0x1789bf322769] [/home/james/Development/usefulFuncs/testy.js:~15] [pc=0x2c94289f2c62](this=0x18b546d884d9 <JSGlobal Object>)
    3: /* anonymous */ [0x1789bf3227a9] [/home/james/Development/usefulFuncs/testy.js:28] [bytecode=0x3630c94b2b59 offset=18](this=0x1789bf3228d9 <Object map = 0x2d17b4e02a41>,exports...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x7f1a1c891328 node::Abort() [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 2: 0x7f1a1c891371  [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 3: 0x7f1a1ca72832 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 4: 0x7f1a1ca72a88 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 5: 0x7f1a1ce017b2  [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 6: 0x7f1a1ce12203 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 7: 0x7f1a1ce12af6 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 8: 0x7f1a1ce1523d v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
 9: 0x7f1a1ce15292 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
10: 0x7f1a1cde3bf4 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
11: 0x7f1a1d04e4e5 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.64]
12: 0x2c942895452b 
Aborted
```

if it is set to `true` the script runs through to completion

in the actual script where i found this issue i tried storing the data in files in a folder on the hard disk. the total size of the folder was in the kilobytes range, however when i push to an array instead the size of the nodejs process seems to inflate exponentially into the multiple gigabytes range...

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: I had just the opposite at the testing: With `log = true` it **crashed** my FireFox but with  `log = false` it takes about **20 seconds** and the script ends without error or ar any output. That's a thing I can understand better the amount of output was too much.

Comment: node is a different engine than FF

Comment: FF uses the Gecko engine, if you dont have Node.js then i suggest using Chrome to run this. Node is based on chromes V8 engine